# For a cdf, $F(F^{-1}(u)) \geq u$ and $F^{-1}(F(x)) \leq x$. When does strict inequality apply?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

For the cdf of a random variable X, we have:

$F(F^{-1}(u)) \geq u$ and $F^{-1}(F(x)) \leq x$, for $u \in [0,1]$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Note that $F^{-1} = Q_F = \inf \{x: F(x) \geq u\}$ is the corresponding quantile function.

My question is: when do we have strict inequality ?

For the first inequality, would it be when we have a discontinuous cdf with a jump, and our $u^*$ is located within the jump ?

That is, our cdf jumps from $u_1$ to $u_2$ at $x_0$ and our $u^* \in (u_1,u_2)$.

Thus, $F^{-1}(u^*) = x_0 \Rightarrow F(F^{-1}(u^*)) = F(x_0) = u_2 > u^*$.

For the second inequality, would it be for a constant region in the cdf from, say, $x_1$ to $x_2$ with our $x^* \in (x_1,x_2)$ ?

So $F(x^*) = u \Rightarrow F^{-1}(F(x^*)) = F^{-1}(u) = x_1 < x^*$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks correct.

To summarize, if the CDF is invertible, then your identities hold with equality. If it is not invertible, it is either because it is not injective or not surjective.

If it is not injective (e.g. it is constant over some interval), it doesn't have a left inverse so that $F^{-1}\circ F(x)\leq x$ should generally not hold with equality for some $x\in \mathbb{R}.$

If it is not surjective (e.g. it has jump discontinuities or atoms), it doesn't have a right inverse so that $F\circ F^{-1}(u)\geq u$ should generally not hold with equality for some $u\in [0,1].$

Comment: thank you, this is perfect. Can you clarify what you mean by left/right inverse? Does that just mean that the cdf is not left or right continuous?

Comment: Nothing to do with continuity (a CDF is always right continuous).  We say a function $f$ is left-invertible when there is some function $g$ such that $g\circ f$ is the identity map. Similar for right inverse.  A function is invertible when it is both left and right invertible.

Comment: As for their connections with injectivity/surjectivity, you can check out proofs here:http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs2800/2015fa/lectures/lec06-proofs.html